# Error in base_name argument in register() in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm working in Django Rest Framework.And I have defined a view set in the views.py file like this:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets

from profiles_api import serializers


class HelloApiView(APIView):
    """Test API View"""
    serializer_class = serializers.HelloSerializer

    def get(self,request,format=None):
        """Returns a list of APIView features"""
        an_apiview = [
            'Uses HTTP methods as functions (get, post, patch, put, delete)',
            'Is similar to a traditional Django View',
            'Gives you the most control over your logic',
            'Is mapped manually to URLs',
        ]

        return Response({'message': 'Hello!', 'an_apiview': an_apiview})

    def post(self, request):
        """Create a hello message with our name"""
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.validated_data.get('name')
            message = f'Hello {name}!'
            return Response({'message': message})
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors,
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )

    def put(self, request, pk=None):
        """Handle updating an object"""

        return Response({'method': 'PUT'})

    def patch(self, request, pk=None):
        """Handle partial update of object"""

        return Response({'method': 'PATCH'})

    def delete(self, request, pk=None):
        """Delete an object"""

        return Response({'method': 'DELETE'})

class HelloViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """Test API ViewSet"""

    def list(self, request):
        """Return a hello message."""

        a_viewset = [
            'Uses actions (list, create, retrieve, update, partial_update)',
            'Automatically maps to URLS using Routers',
            'Provides more functionality with less code',
        ]

        return Response({'message': 'Hello!', 'a_viewset': a_viewset})
```

And I have registered the router for the view set in the urls.py as:

```
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from profiles_api import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('hello-viewset', views.HelloViewSet, base_name='hello-viewset')


urlpatterns = [
    path('hello-view/', views.HelloApiView.as_view()),
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

But when I run the command `python manage.py runserver` its showing the error

> TypeError: register() got an unexpected argument 'base_name'

So what should I do to rectify this error??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `basename` instead of `base_name`

Answer (score 1):

The only mistake was using base_name instead of basename

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answer. Accept/up-vote the answer that worked for you.  Worth reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)